# PHP regular expression to match exact string

Tags: php, regex

I have string like "ABC 1000", "ABC 1", "ABC 100".

In above string example, first 3 character i.e. ABC is fixed every time and then digits, digits can be long upto N numbers.

In 2nd part i.e. after "ABC " it should always be numberic value, no alphabet, no special symbol.

So, how can I manage with regular expression. Please help.

I have tried with following but failed ..

```
$var="ABC 100";

preg_match("/^INR /[0-9]+/", $var)
```

Comment: Fail to see how `INR` == `ABC`.

Answer (score 5):

You have an extra `/` in your regular expression. It should be:

```
preg_match('/^ABC \d+/', $var);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
^[A-Za-z]{3} *\d+$
```

http://regex101.com/r/gE4mS4

```
$var="ABC 100";
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]{3} *\d+$/", $var)
```

- 3 letters (case insensitive)
- 0 or more space
- 1 or more digits